# I can not see a QR Code in a PDF report with GX X EVO3

Tags: c#, genexus

I need to find the solution to print a QR code in a PDF report. In a procedure report I have in the source the following:

```
&txtBase64 = & webQrCode.Get ('ws_txtQRBase64')
&txtBase64 = substr (& txtBase64,23,5000)
&qrBlob.FromBase64String (& txtBase64)
&qrPrint = & qrBlob
//qrPrint is of type Image and qrBlob of type blob.
```

In a small project (Windows 10) there are no problems to see the QR code in the report. But when you import it from another, which is where it should work (Windows XP 32bits), it does not show the image in the report. It was tested with Chrome and FireFox. The problem will be the Windows version? In both computers the .NET 3.5 is used

**Can you guide me to solve it? Thank you!!! Use GX X Evo3 U11. C #**

Comment: Please share your attempts

Comment: Hi. Sorry. I was stuck. I have tried to generate a text file and open it in the procedure, but the results are the same as when using a WebSession variable. The content of this variable can be seen in the report. I understand that the problem is not the base64, but the Blob that does not allow me to see it in the report.